# ImportError for packages in my current environment

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to revive some old IPython notebooks and update them to Python 3. I am trying to get them working first in the old environment and finding an intractable difficulty, getting ImportErrors for packages in my current environment. I am working on an Anaconda Python installation.

I start my notebook by first navigating to the folder of my project:

```
cd /folder/of/project
```

and then:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I create a new notebook and here is an extract from `!conda list` inside the notebook and the errors I am getting:

```
# packages in environment at /anaconda2:
#

...
Delorean                  0.6.0                     <pip>
...
pylint                    1.7.2            py27h718c7e7_0  
pymongo                   3.4.0                    py27_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.17           py27hc9de18c_0  
...
```

Clearly, the packages of interest, `Delorean` and `pymongo`, are in the environment. `pymongo` was installed via `conda` natively, but `Delorean` can only be installed via `pip`.

`[1] import pymongo`

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-ec8fdd1cd630> in <module>()
----> 1 import pymongo


ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

`[2] from delorean import Delorean`

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-2b02cbe45080> in <module>()
----> 1 from delorean import Delorean


ImportError: No module named delorean
```

I have tried this on various virtual environments created using conda as well as in the default environment. I have looked at various questions on StackOverflow and still getting no solution.

In response to a comment, here are the paths to jupyter and python:

```
$ which jupyter

/anaconda2/bin/jupyter

$ which python

/anaconda2/bin/python
```

To compound the mystery, trying to import the packages from python shell as suggested by @Sraw, works perfectly.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Sep 21 2017, 17:38:20)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo
>>> from delorean import Delorean
>>>
```

The issue therefore is limited to inside the jupyter notebook.

Comment: Pretty sure that you don't run your script in the correct environment. How do you start it?

Comment: Did you launch your `jupyter` in the same environment but not another environment?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to describe how I start the notebook. The error repeats even when I do not use virtual envs.

Comment: Could you print out `which jupyter` to check your jupyter's path and print out `which python` to check out your python's path? I mean, in the same terminal.

Comment: yes do `which python`, if the executable path is not the one in conda, add conda's bin in the `PATH`

Comment: I have listed the output of which commands at the bottom of the question. I am frustrated because I know the answer is simple... apologetic for taking people's time here.

Comment: It is strange... it seems no problem about your environment. Could you import those two packages in python shell?

Comment: Thanks @Sraw -- I did this and the import works from shell (added the output to the end of the question)

Comment: Try to launch your `jupyter` by `python -m jupyter notebook`. Will it work?

Comment: I tried that but to no avail. IPython shell, though, succeeds also in importing the packages... something is changing when I get to the notebook environment.

Comment: Using @Sraw's leads, I have tried `import sys` and `sys.path` and discovered that the notebook was looking down old, invalid paths for the packages and avoiding the valid ones. I am trying to resolve these issues now.

Comment: Hope you can resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. It was created by my trying to juggle different Python 2 and 3 versions and multiple trial virtual environments. I had ended up with an old user-specific anaconda installation and a new anaconda root for all users. The discovery was made by finding that

```
import sys
sys.path
```

gave different reports when I ran these from Python shell and from inside the notebook.

I cleared the user-specific anaconda installation, re-installed the latest anaconda version, added the relevant packages, and installed parallel ipython kernels ([as described here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html)).

The issue is resolved and serves as a lesson in the importance of keeping the root python install clean and properly using virtual environments.